# How can I set the nav title's tint color for a modal interface in WatchKit?

Tags: ios, watchkit

In WatchKit, I know that I can set the "Global Tint" value in my storyboard file to adjust the navigation title's text color in my interface controllers.

However, whenever I present a modal interface controller in my application, I'm noticing that the InterfaceController's title shows up as white, not the global tint color.

Here's my tint color setting on the storyboard file:

[image]

Here's an example of the issue I'm finding:

[image: no tint on modal nav]

**How can I get the title of a modal to use the global tint color?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the current SDK, you are not able to change the title color of Modal screens. The title will always be white.

The global tint color does not apply to Interface Controllers presented modally.

Comment: Do you have a link to the HIG or to a forum thread about this? I'm hesitant to give up on this problem, because the title color's tint shows up in Storyboards - this feels more like a bug than a HIG thing.

Comment: I've also tried everything to change the title color of presented controller but no luck. If you've fixed please assist me as well.

Comment: it is still an issue, as far as I can see... I also haven't managed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're manually changing the title on the Model Interface Controller from 'Close' to 'Modal View'. Usually it would display 'Close' and I believe the Tint Colour might only apply to wherever your App's Executable Name is displayed.

I might be wrong, and I understand your confusion. Try filing a bug report for this issue or raising it in the [WatchKit Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/watchkit)?